# How to create a custom int type in python

Tags: python, arrays, memory, data-structures, integer

I have a big numpy array (290000, 513, 126) and I want to store it in 13 bit integer to gain some space for later computations (I need it to fit in RAM).

Basically, I want to do somehting like this :

```
dataset = np.empty((290000, 513, 126), dtype=np.int13) # or int13
```

I cannot find any clear info on how to define such structure, any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Would 13-bit integers really save space? By default I would expect each number to be stored as a separate computer word, even if the wordsize is bigger than the number of bits requested by numpy. Besides, 13 is a weird size in a world where everything fits in powers of 2.

Comment: It will shave a few gigabytes and I need this for the data to fit in 128gb ram space. When I switch from np.int16 to np.int8, it does decrease the size. I agree it is ugly tho

Comment: I suspect numpy is smart enough to store more than one np.int8 per word, to save space. But it's going to be a simple relation, like "4 np.int8 per word" if a word is 32bits. With int13, you can't have such a simple relation, so it's going to have to be something more complex like "32 int13 per 13 words". Of course, it's technically possible to save data like this if it's really what you want, but then you won't have any efficient way to perform arithmetic operations on this stored data.

Comment: I undestand. I will convert it back to int16 in batches and this will be sufficient for what I want to do. But maybe it is not the best approach. I have a big dataset that I want to feed to an autoencoder but I can't use a generator because I have IO bottleneck (I tried to solve it but I see no clear solution). If I don't load the dataset in RAM, one epoch is ten times longer to complete